# How to require positional arguments when using decorators?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, decorator, python-decorators

I need to a create a generic decorator that validates parameters passed to multiple python functions, that have similar arguments, but not necessarily in the same order.

The python functions are part of an SDK, so the arguments need to be readable (i.e. can't just be `*args` and `**kwargs` as that would require the user to dig through the code.)

Let's consider the following decorator, which enforces the constraint that `a` > `b`:

```
from functools import wraps

def check_args(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(self, *args, **kwargs):
        a = kwargs["a"]
        b = kwargs["b"]
        
        if a < b:
            raise ValueError("a must be strictly greater than b")

        return f(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return decorated_function
```

Now consider the following example:

```
class MyClass(object):
    
    @check_args
    def f(self, *, a, b):
        return a + b
```

Let's call the method `f` and pass in `a` and `b` as keyword-arguments:

```
MyClass().f(a=2, b=1)
```

This works as expected, no errors.

Now's let again call the method `f`, but this time using arguments:

```
MyClass().f(1, 2)
```

This raises a KeyError:

```
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
  Input In [15], in <cell line: 7>()
        3     @check_args
        4     def f(self, *, a, b):
        5         return a + b
  ----> 7 MyClass().f(1, 2)

  Input In [14], in check_args.<locals>.decorated_function(self, *args, **kwargs)
        4 @wraps(f)
        5 def decorated_function(self, *args, **kwargs):
  ----> 6     a = kwargs["a"]
        7     b = kwargs["b"]
        9     if a < b:

  KeyError: 'a'
```

The parameters are now coming into the decorator as `args`, which means I would need to reference them as args[0], args[1]. But then how would I make the decorator generic? What if I want to use the decorator on a different function, which has a different starting parameter?

Moreover, I added the `*` to the list of arguments for f, to force the user to use `keyword` arguments, but instead, the decorator raised a KeyError.

If I remove the decorator:

```
class MyClass(object):
    
    def f(self, *, a, b):
        return a + b
    
MyClass().f(2, 1)
```

I get a different error:

```
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
  Input In [19], in <cell line: 6>()
        3     def f(self, *, a, b):
        4         return a + b
  ----> 6 MyClass().f(2, 1)

  TypeError: f() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

which is the error I want, as that forces the user to use `keyword` arguments!

What's the proper solution for this problem? How do I force the user to use `keyword` arguments when using decorators?

Edit: A  `hack` would be to examine the list of `args` and raise an error if this list is non-empty. But that sounds like a cheat, is there a proper solution?

Comment: Dump the `*args` from inner method in decorator signature. (granted, the type error will mention `decorated_function`, not `f`)

Comment: Thanks! I did try that, and as you mentioned, the `type error` points to the `decorated function`. Ideally, the error should point to `f`

Comment: Wait, what? `type error` should point to `f` with `wraps` and `decorated_function` without. Isn't it what you expected?

Comment: If I remove `args` from the decorator, and call MyClass().f(2, 1) it throws a `TypeError: decorated_function() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given`, which points to the `decorator` not `f`

Comment: Your post is titled "how to require positional arguments" (*args), but what you're asking is how to require keyword arguments (**kwargs).

Comment: You should express yourself more accurately. It seems like you are mixing args and kwargs together to me. Do you want to call the same decorated method sometimes with args and sometimes with kwargs? Can you show an example of what you expect the decorator to be used on 2 different methods? You want to check arguments of methods with different arguments so maybe you want pass arguments to tell it how to check the decorated function?

Answer (score 2):

try inspect.getfullargspec()

```
from functools import wraps
import inspect

def check_args(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(inspect.getfullargspec(f))
        a = kwargs["a"]
        b = kwargs["b"]
        
        if a < b:
            raise ValueError("a must be strictly greater than b")

        return f(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return decorated_function

class MyClass(object):
    
    @check_args
    def f(self, *, a, b):
        return a + b

MyClass().f(1, 2)
```

it see the names:

```
FullArgSpec(args=['self'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=None, kwonlyargs=['a', 'b'], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})
```

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite args to kwargs ??? maybe it not looks good, but it's working, and if you realy must...

```
def check_decorator(f):
    def wrapper(self,  **kwargs):
        if "a" in kwargs.keys():
            a = kwargs["a"]
        if "b" in kwargs.keys():
            b = kwargs["b"]

        if a < b:
            raise ValueError("a must be strictly greater than b")
        f(self, a, b)
    return wrapper


def change_args_decorator(fun):
    def wrapper_f(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if len(args) > 0:
            kwargs["a"] = args[0]
        if len(args) > 1:
            kwargs["b"] = args[1]
        fun(self,  **kwargs)
    return wrapper_f


class MyClass(object):
    @change_args_decorator
    @check_decorator
    def f(self,  a, b):
        print(a + b)
        return a + b


MyClass().f(2, 1)
MyClass().f(a=2, b=1)
MyClass().f(b=2, a=5)
MyClass().f(2, b=1)

3
3
7
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `a` and `b` are required keyword parameters, why not explicitly mark them in the decorator?

```
from functools import wraps


def check_args(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(self, *args, a, b, **kwargs):
        if a < b:
            raise ValueError("a must be strictly greater than b")

        return f(self, *args, a=a, b=b, **kwargs)

    return decorated_function
```

Test:

```
In [16]: MyClass().f(2, 1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [16], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 MyClass().f(2, 1)

TypeError: MyClass.f() missing 2 required keyword-only arguments: 'a' and 'b'

In [17]: MyClass().f(a=2, b=1)
Out[17]: 3
```